# how to clear text on a window in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, blit

In my game That I am making. I am trying to resolve this problem that I Have with the game over screen.

the problem is when you die it says 'You died' then I put 'Play again' or 'Quit'. If you press Quit Obviously it quits the game but if you press Play again what I want it to do is to rerun the program.

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, w, h))
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x + (w / 2)), (y + (h / 2)))
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)



def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def dead():
    global dead
    dead = True
    
    while dead:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("You Died", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Play Again", 20, 450, 115, 50, green, bright_green, respawn)
        button("Quit", 250, 450, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
```

for my respawn function. Someone told me to copy and paste every thing in my while true loop and put it all in my respawn function and what I have noticed is that when you press play again the music and the sound effects are playing and all but the game over screen is still playing

in case you need it here is the code for the respawn function

```
def respawn():
    global dead
    global run
    global velotimeser 
    global timeForLevel 
    global font 
    global man 
    global zombie 
    global zombie1 

    global randomside 
    global gunCapacity 
    global points
    global powerMeter 
    global bullets 
    global intro 
    dead = False
    velotimeser = 1
    timeForLevel = 0
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30, True)
    man = Player(300, 508, 64, 64)
    zombie = Enemy(100, 508, 64, 64, 450)
    zombie1 = Enemy1(100, 508, 64, 64, 450)

    randomside = 0
    gunCapacity = 1
    points = 0
    powerMeter = 0
    bullets = []
    intro = False

    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    run = True
    while run and dead == False:

        clock.tick(27)
        #this is the hitbox for when the zombie collides with the player and the player hasnt shot a bullet or has launched a punch that it should deduct a peice of health and 5 points and move the player back depending on where the zombie is facing


        timeForLevel += 0.05
        
        
        


        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie.hitbox[1] + zombie.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie.hitbox[0] + zombie.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == False and zombie.visible == True and zombie.velo > 0 and man.x > zombie.x:
                man.x += 15
                pygame.time.delay(10)
                points -= 5
                man.hit()

        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie.hitbox[1] + zombie.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie.hitbox[0] + zombie.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == False and zombie.visible == True and zombie.velo > 0 and man.x < zombie.x:
                man.x -= 15
                pygame.time.delay(10)
                points -= 5
                man.hit()

        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie.hitbox[1] + zombie.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie.hitbox[0] + zombie.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == False and zombie.visible == True and zombie.velo < 0 and man.x <= zombie.x:
                man.x -= 15
                pygame.time.delay(10)
                points -= 5
                man.hit()

        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie.hitbox[1] + zombie.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie.hitbox[0] + zombie.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == False and zombie.visible == True and zombie.velo < 0 and man.x > zombie.x:
                man.x += 15
                pygame.time.delay(10)
                points -= 5
                man.hit()

        

        #this hitbox detects if the player is touching the zombie whilst punching it
        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie.hitbox[1] + zombie.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie.hitbox[0] + zombie.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == True and zombie.visible == True:
                if zombie.velo < 0 and zombie.x < man.x:
                    zombie.x = zombie.x - 15
                    zombie.hit()
                    points += 5
                if zombie.velo < 0 and zombie.x > man.x:
                    zombie.x = zombie.x + 15
                    zombie.hit()
                    points += 5
                if zombie.velo > 0 and zombie.x > man.x:
                    zombie.x = zombie.x + 15
                    zombie.hit()
                    points += 5
                if zombie.velo > 0 and zombie.x < man.x:
                    zombie.x = zombie.x - 15
                    zombie.hit()
                    points += 5

        #this is the hitbox for when the zombie collides with the player and the player hasnt shot a bullet or has launched a punch that it should deduct a peice of health and 5 points and move the player back depending on where the zombie is facing
        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie1.hitbox[1] + zombie1.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie1.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie1.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie1.hitbox[0] + zombie1.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == False and zombie1.visible == True and zombie.velo > 0 and man.x > zombie1.x:
                man.x += 15
                pygame.time.delay(10)
                points -= 5
                man.hit()

        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie1.hitbox[1] + zombie1.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie1.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie1.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie1.hitbox[0] + zombie1.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == False and zombie1.visible == True and zombie.velo > 0 and man.x < zombie1.x:
                man.x += 15
                pygame.time.delay(10)
                points -= 5
                man.hit()
                
        #same thing here expet its for when the zombie is facing left       
        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie1.hitbox[1] + zombie1.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie1.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie1.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie1.hitbox[0] + zombie1.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == False and zombie1.visible == True and zombie1.velo < 0 and man.x < zombie1.x:
                man.x -= 15
                pygame.time.delay(10)
                points -= 5
                man.hit()

        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie1.hitbox[1] + zombie1.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie1.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie1.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie1.hitbox[0] + zombie1.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == False and zombie1.visible == True and zombie1.velo < 0 and man.x > zombie1.x:
                man.x -= 15
                pygame.time.delay(10)
                points -= 5
                man.hit()

        #this hitbox detects if the player is touching the zombie whilst punching it
        if man.hitbox[1] < zombie1.hitbox[1] + zombie1.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] > zombie1.hitbox[1]:
            if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > zombie1.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < zombie1.hitbox[0] + zombie1.hitbox[2] and man.punchislaunched == True and zombie1.visible == True:
                    if zombie1.velo < 0 and zombie1.x < man.x:
                        zombie1.x = zombie1.x - 15
                        zombie1.hit()
                        points += 1
                    if zombie1.velo < 0 and zombie1.x > man.x:
                        zombie1.x = zombie1.x + 15
                        zombie1.hit()
                        points += 1
                    if zombie1.velo > 0 and zombie1.x > man.x:
                        zombie1.x = zombie1.x + 15
                        zombie1.hit()
                        points += 1
                    if zombie1.velo > 0 and zombie1.x < man.x:
                        zombie1.x = zombie1.x - 15
                        zombie1.hit()
                        points += 1
                        

        #this tels it to shoot one bullet at a time instead of sending a group of bullets to the zombie
        if gunCapacity > 0:
            gunCapacity += 1
        if gunCapacity> 10:
            gunCapacity = 0

        #this tels it to close the programe if you press the big red cross at the top right
        for event in pygame.event.get():


            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
           
        #this sets the collision for when the zombie  touches the bullet
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < zombie.hitbox[1] + zombie.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > zombie.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > zombie.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < zombie.hitbox[0] + zombie.hitbox[2] and zombie.visible == True:
                    if zombie.velo < 0 and zombie.x < man.x:
                        zombie.x = zombie.x - 15
                        zombie.hit()
                        points += 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    if zombie.velo < 0 and zombie.x > man.x:
                        zombie.x = zombie.x + 15
                        zombie.hit()
                        points += 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    if zombie.velo > 0 and zombie.x > man.x:
                        zombie.x = zombie.x + 15
                        zombie.hit()
                        points += 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    if zombie.velo > 0 and zombie.x < man.x:
                        zombie.x = zombie.x - 15
                        zombie.hit()
                        points += 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

                    
                    
                        

            #this tells the bullet to delete itself if it touches the the end of the screen
            if bullet.x < 600 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x += bullet.velo
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

        
        #this sets the collision for when the zombie  touches the bullet
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < zombie1.hitbox[1] + zombie1.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > zombie1.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > zombie1.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < zombie1.hitbox[0] + zombie1.hitbox[2] and zombie1.visible == True:
                    if zombie1.velo < 0 and zombie1.x < man.x:
                        zombie1.x = zombie1.x - 15
                        zombie1.hit()
                        points += 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    if zombie1.velo < 0 and zombie1.x > man.x:
                        zombie1.x = zombie1.x + 15
                        zombie1.hit()
                        points += 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    if zombie1.velo > 0 and zombie1.x > man.x:
                        zombie1.x = zombie1.x + 15
                        zombie1.hit()
                        points += 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    if zombie1.velo > 0 and zombie1.x < man.x:
                        zombie1.x = zombie1.x - 15
                        zombie1.hit()
                        points += 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
            #this tells the bullet to delete itself if it touches the the end of the screen
            if bullet.x < 600 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x += bullet.velo
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

        
        if timeForLevel > 20:
            velotimeser = 1.0002
            zombie.velo = zombie.velo * velotimeser
            zombie1.velo = zombie1.velo * velotimeser


        

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        #these are the keaboard bings for all the functions
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.velo:
            man.x -= man.velo
            man.right = False
            man.left = True
            man.Idlecount = 0
            man.guncount = 0
            man.gunisfired = False
            man.standing = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 600 - man.width - man.velo:
            man.x += man.velo
            man.right = True
            man.left = False
            man.Idlecount = 0
            man.guncount = 0
            man.gunisfired = False
            man.standing = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            man.gunisfired = True
            man.isIdle = False
            man.standing = True
            man.Idlecount = 0
            man.punchislaunched = False
            man.walkcount = 0
        
        elif keys[pygame.K_x]:
            man.gunisfired = False
            man.isIdle = False
            man.standing = True
            man.Idlecount = 0
            man.guncount = 0
            man.punchislaunched = True
        else:
            man.walkcount = 0
            man.isIdle = True
            man.guncount = 0
            man.gunisfired = False
            man.standing = True
            man.punchislaunched = False
            man.punchcount = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and gunCapacity == 0:
            
            if man.left:
                facing = -1
            else:
                facing = 1
            if len(bullets) < 5:
                bullets.append(Projectile(round(man.x + man.width //2), round(man.y + man.height//2), 6, (0,0,0), facing))
                bulletSound.play()
            gunCapacity = 1

        #this tells the zombie to respawn when it is dead
        if zombie.visible == False:
            randomside = random.randint(1,4)
            if randomside == 1:
                zombie.x = 20
            if randomside ==2:
                zombie.x = 580
            if randomside ==3:
                zombie.x = 580
                zombie1.x = 520
                zombie1.visible = True
                zombie1.health = 10
                zombie1.draw(screen)
            if randomside == 4:
                zombie.x = 20
                zombie1.x = 80
                zombie1.visible = True
                zombie1.health = 10
                zombie1.draw(screen)

            zombie.visible = True
            zombie.health = 10
            zombie.draw(screen)
        print(randomside)

 

    
    
       
    redrawGameWindow()
    Timetext = font.render('Time elapsed:' + str(round(timeForLevel,1)), 1, (255,251,0))
    screen.blit(Timetext, (20, 10))
    

    pygame.display.update()
```

if that is enough code to show check my [Git hub](https://github.com/ZeeScratcher/Errors-from-the-2D-post-apocolyptic-shooter-)

can get an explanation how this is happening or how I can fix it

Comment: _"Someone told me to copy and paste every thing in my while true loop and put it all in my respawn function"_ They most likely told you to put everything that's *before* the while loop into a `respawn` function. It's so you can reset all variables.

Comment: Don't copy and paste your entire `while True` loop. That's not a sensible solution. Instead try and set every variables in your game to the initial state.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the tips as you said I should have just set the variables to their original conditions. Like this

```
def respawn():
    global dead
    global run
    global velotimeser 
    global timeForLevel 
    global font 
    global man 
    global zombie 
    global zombie1 

    global randomside 
    global gunCapacity 
    global points
    global powerMeter 
    global bullets 
    global intro 
    dead = False
    velotimeser = 1
    timeForLevel = 0
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30, True)
    man = Player(300, 508, 64, 64)
    zombie = Enemy(100, 508, 64, 64, 450)
    zombie1 = Enemy1(100, 508, 64, 64, 450)

    randomside = 0
    gunCapacity = 1
    points = 0
    powerMeter = 0
    bullets = []
    intro = False

    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    run = True
```